# Why does ir-keytable quit?

Tags: raspberry-pi4, lirc

To set IR on my clean Raspberry Pi 4, I am following the instructions at https://learn.pi-supply.com/make/ir-remote-control-support-on-raspbian-buster-justboom/.

One step at the beginning, even before installing lirc package, is to install and run ir-keytable:

```
$ sudo apt install ir-keytable
$ sudo ir-keytable
```

This command shows that my driver is gpio_ir_recv and the device is /dev/lirc1. Perfect.

Next, I run the command to test receiving IR signals:

```
$ sudo ir-keytable -c -p all -t
```

However, this command quits as soon as it is run. There are no new messages in /var/log/ folder either.

Wondering why this command would simply quit.

Note that lirc package as not yet been installed. As per the article, this step comes later.

Comment: I have the same question. I don't know the answer yet but I found this https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/106770/lirc-mode2-shows-no-output and I think there are more clues when you run `cat /proc/bus/input/devices` and `ls /dev/input/event*`